# How to add component "hidden" and then slide it in?

Tags: javascript, animation, extjs, extjs4

I want to do basically the following - add a panel to a parent panel, but this child panel  should be hidden ad first. Than, after layout is done (and, therefore, getEl() is available) I want to invoke slideIn method.

The problem is I don't know how exactly how it should be hidden. 
I've tried to hide panel in beforeLayout event and then to show it just after slideIn began, but this does not work as expected.

I've also tried to add some css properties (display: none or visibility: hidden) and then to remove them, but this also don't worked correctly.

**UPD:** some code to clarify my problem:

```
var panel = new Ext.panel.Panel({
   title: "child",
   layout: "fit",
   beforeLayout: function() {
      //here we are trying to hide the panel
      panel.getEl().addCls("somehiddenclass"); //actually display:none
   } 
})

parent_panel.add(panel);
panel.slideIn("l");
panel.getEl().removeCls("somehiddenclass");
```

Comment: Some code would move this along rather nicely. JSFiddle is even better.

Comment: @ZenMaster - Let me provide some code here - for the sake of speed and after, if needed, use JSFiddle, which is definitely awesome service.

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply initialise the panel with `hidden: true` and then call the slideIn functionality after the control has been created?

Comment: @dougjmcdonald - this actually won't help. It looks like it helps to get rid of beforeLayout event (which sadly triggers several times) - but trying just call slideIn won't show up the panel.

Comment: before slidein you do setVisible(true) for the component

Answer (score 0):

another solution might be to enclose your panel in simple div element or much easier to control Ext.Container control and set its style respectively.